# Find Element By Id Katalon Studio

Tags: katalon-studio

Is there a way to find element by id in Katalon studio instead of Xpath?

I tried using

`Mobile.tap((TestObject)driver.findElementsByAccessibilityId("input_email"), 0)`

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your object by CSS:

```
TestObject yourObject = new TestObject()
yourObject.addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, '#input_email')
Mobile.tap(yourObject, 0)
```

Comment: When I use your suggestion the test passes but without finding the input object

Comment: What do you mean? Is Mobile.tap() executed? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No I don't get any errors and Mobile.tap() is not executed

Comment: yes it is even when the tap method was not executed